# Add Event Listener to Array index

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, promise

I have an array that is being filled on page load by D3. I want to access that same array at another time but I still need to confirm that it has been loaded.

I don't know the propper way to do this so I just guessed a few time and I kept getting "not a function" errors

First Code (populate my svg, snapshot of current values)

```
d3.tsv("file.txt").then( function(data) { Loaded_Data[1]=data; document.getElementById("valve1").innerHTML = data[data.length-1]['OnOff']; //etc 
 });
```

much later, but still in a relevant timescale of async, I want to do some d3 graphing with this data, but I want to make sure that there is data in my array.

Later Code (populate graphs, weeks of data)

```
Loaded_Data[1].addEventListener('load', () => {console.log("success"); //d3.graphing; });
```

I basically want a:
while (array[1] is undefined){ Listen; }
when done => graph;

Or would it just be easier to load the entire set of documents again in another d3.tsv().then()? it seems like a waste of resources to reload the entire data. What makes this difficult is the number of sources I have to load in, and consolidating my data into one array will be (hopefully) more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

just graph in the `then` call after you read the data:

```
  d3.tsv("file.txt")
    .then(data => graph(data)); //data is available to be used at this point
```

also, if I'm reading this correctly, you are listening for the array to be populated with the `load` event, but that is only fired when the whole page is loaded and isn't relevant to the populating of a data structure.  If you need the data stored somewhere in addition to graphing, you could modify the above to:

```
  d3.tsv("file.txt")
    .then(data => {
      graph(data);
      myArray = data;
    });
```